# how to show/ hide column in a extjs 3 grid panel

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have a grid panel i need to show / hide columns in a grid panel depending on the value of a checkbox. If the checkbox is checked i need to display column in the grid and if it is unchecked i need to hide the column in the grid.

Here is my code

```
var chkEnableDisplayResponsibilityForAction = '<%=Session["chkEnableDisplayResponsibilityForAction"]%>';

 var flags = Boolean.parse(chkEnableDisplayResponsibilityForAction);
 var flags1 = !Boolean.parse(chkEnableDisplayResponsibilityForAction)

 var colModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
 { header: "PricePlanID", width: 100, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'PricePlanID', hidden: flags, hideable: flags1 },
  ]);
```

when i refresh the page i am not able to toggle the columns depending on the value of the checkbox. But when i login and log out i am able to see the changes in the grid panel. Can anyone help me in refreshing the column values in the grid panel?

Comment: 18k views in two minutes.....

Comment: ExtJs 4: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042138/extjs4-what-is-the-equivalent-to-the-grid-columnmodel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ExtJs4 - What is the equivalent to the grid ColumnModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042138/extjs4-what-is-the-equivalent-to-the-grid-columnmodel)

Answer (score 25):

if take a look at the ExtJS API, particulary the [ColumModel](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.ColumnModel) there is a `setHidden` method, it would hide/show a column in a `GridPanel`.

```
myGrid.getColumnModel().setHidden(0, true);
```

you should also hook the `onchange` event of your check box so you can show or hide the column

Comment: Checkbox is in another page to which a flag is set and depending on the value of the flag column in the grid panel is visible or hidden.It is working perfect now.
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: This is deprecated in 4.0+

Answer (score 13):

In Ext JS 4.1, to hide a column, you use:

```
grid.columns[0].setVisible(false);
```

Looks like getColumnModel() with its setHidden() method is no longer part of the grid:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel

Comment: shorthand : grid.columns[0].hide() 
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/AbstractElement.html#Ext-dom-AbstractElement-method-hide

Answer (score 3):

You can show/hide columns using column header menu - you can choose which column you want to have shown. Anyway, if you want to show/hide a column, try this

```
myGrid.getColumnModel().setHidden(0, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

In ExtJS 4 gain access to your grid panel, and then access the columns attribute which is an array of Column objects.

From there you can use the  array iterator methods ( http://www.diveintojavascript.com/core-javascript-reference/the-array-object ) to perform an action.

In the below example I hide and show a few of the columns based on their header names, but you can obviously perform action based on any Column attribute.

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp( 'my_grid_panel' );

grid.columns.forEach( function( col ) {
   if( ( col.text == "Foo" ) || ( col.text == "Bar" ) ) {
      col.setVisible( true );
   } else if( col.text == "Baz" ) {
      col.setVisible( false );
   }
});
```

Comment: The only issue here being that - Say there are six columns and you want to show five initially and then show the sixth only if the checkbox is checked . and in my case with the code above , it shows all six columns [ col.hidden = true ] works in that case .
 And So i ended up setting the hidden as true for all columns initially . And running this code in beforerender . That works

Answer (score 1):

The answers above I think are pretty good.
But let me give you a advice.

1) In **ExtJS 4.x** it is recommended to use **Ext.ComponentQuery**`s methods instead of *Ext.getCmp()*

2) To hide/show columns of the grid you can use following code

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('grid gridcolumn[dataIndex^="service"]')[0].hide()
```

or to show

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('grid gridcolumn[dataIndex^="service"]')[0].show()
```

It should resolve hiding/showing any column in a grid.

Here *grid* is your grid , it maybe id or xtype etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
setVisibleColumn       : function(name, flag) {
    name = Ext.Array.from(name);
    var column;

    for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        column = this.getColumn(name[i]);
        if (column) {
            flag ? column.show() : column.hide();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation to your answer?