# extjs show/hide column dynamically

Tags: extjs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to show/ hide column in a grid panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797621/how-to-show-hide-column-in-a-grid-panel)

In an ext js grid, I have the requirement of hiding/showing a column based on some cond = true/ false.

Can i set the 'hidden' property of a column dynamically?

Comment: Is this after the column/grid are already constructed? Or do you know whether you want to show it when you're creating the column definition?

Comment: After grid is constructed, when store loads, store will contain a flag for hide/show

Comment: similar to this imho : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042138/extjs4-what-is-the-equivalent-to-the-grid-columnmodel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `beforerender` event to hide the column. The event is called before the render function is called to display your grid. The event function take a param which is the grid itself. From this grid object you can get the column model of the grid and call `setHidden` method to hide the appropriate column. From the grid object you can also get the store attached to the grid for your check.

Here is how the code will be:

```
listeners: {
    'beforerender' : function(grid) {

        store = grid.getStore();
        if(your-condition) {
            cm = grid.getColumnModel();
            cm.setHidden(0,true);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: i like where you are going with it but it would be nice if it was a more rounded approach like: when the user hides a column, trap the event, store in localStorage the flag for hidding the certain column. Any grid loading script would set the visibility of the column based on whats inside the localStorage for it.

Comment: you could easily extend the above approach to do that!

Comment: i ended up realizing that extjs has a state manager. switched it on and bam! I user configurable grids.

Answer (score 5):

You can check and hide when store loads:

```
store.load({
    callback: function(){
        // access raw json data and check some columns to hide or not
        if(store.getProxy().getReader().rawData.myColumn.hide) {
            grid.columns[1].setVisible(false);
        }
        if(store.getProxy().getReader().rawData.myAnotherColumn.hide) {
            grid.columns[4].setVisible(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -6):

if($('.selector').is(':hidden')) { your_code }

http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Comment: this is not JQuery. We are talking about ExtJs