# ExtJs4 - What is the equivalent to the grid ColumnModel?

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4

What is the equivalent to the ExtJs3 `Ext.grid.ColumnModel` in ExtJs4?

What I want to do is hide a column, I did something like below in ExtJs3:

```
grid.colModel.setHidden(1, true);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can hide/show column using setVisible method of Ext.grid.column.Column:

```
grid.columns[1].setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers can be problematic if your column indexes change.

Here is another solution:

Set itemId on the column definition:

```
{
        itemId: 'myActionColumn',
        xtype: 'actioncolumn',
        width: 50,
        items: [ ...
}
```

Then to hide:

```
grid.down('#myActionColumn').hide();
```

Comment: Great idea, IMO much cleaner than the accepted answer,

Answer (score 2):

Ext.grid.header.Container

code of Ext.panel.Table:

```
 headerCtCfg = me.columns || me.colModel, 
 ...
if (headerCtCfg instanceof Ext.grid.header.Container) {
            me.headerCt = headerCtCfg;
            me.headerCt.border = border;
            me.columns = me.headerCt.items.items;
}
```

so u can use

```
grid.columns[i].hide()/show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution more flexible :

```
grid.down("[dataIndex="+di+"]").setVisible(v);
```

You can change `dataIndex` for another property like `name` or whatever.