# How to dynamically show/hide columns in extjs Grid?

Tags: extjs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to show/ hide column in a grid panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797621/how-to-show-hide-column-in-a-grid-panel)

In extjs gridpanel, there is an attribute called : visibleColumns.
What I want is this:

```
someGrid = new Gridpanel({
store: this.someStore,
flex: 1,
if (someCond=true)
visibleColumns:[
col1,col2
]
else
visibleColumns:[
col3,col4
]
});
```

How to achieve the if (someCond=true) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to try something like that:

```
someGrid.getColumnModel().setHidden(0, true);
```

Comment: I am using extjs v4.1. Is this feature deprecated ? What is the alternative to hide colum/group of columns at **runtime**?

Comment: I do it in beforeRender method as:
this.columns[idx].hide() or .show() depend what i need (where idx is 0-based index of column to hide/show)

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your `someCond` add a `hidden` attribute to the column configuration:

```
[{
    // col1
    hidden: !someCond
}, {
    // col2
    hidden: !someCond
}, {
    // col3
    hidden: someCond
}, {
    // col4
    hidden: someCond
}]
```

Note: Make sure to add hidden attribute to **all** the columns.

Comment: +1 
@himanshu: Why do you say to make sure to add hidden attribute to all the columns? It works even without adding to all the columns.

Comment: @Harshal I think this has to do with the version of ExtJs you are using. My project was using an older version and hiding columns did not work till I added hidden attribute to all the columns